# display Console output in same line in python

Tags: python, output, display

How to iterate through the while loop and display the contents of a list, tuple or any other collection in the same line, separated by commas ensuring that the comma is not displayed at the end?

Example:

```
def display(a):
    i=0
    while(i<len(a)):
        print(a[i],end=",")
        i+=1

a=(10,20,30)
display(a)
```

Output should be :
10,20,30
But i get 10,20,30,
Please give answers other than the method of using ','.join(map(str(a)) or stripping the space by converting it to a string.

Comment: why can't you try -  print a.... or can you mention what output you expect to be precise

Answer (score 0):

You could print the items and then print the commas.

```
def display(a):
    i=0
    while(i<(len(a))):
        print(a[i],end="")
        if(i<(len(a)-1)):
            print(",", end="")
        i += 1

a = (10,20,30)
display(a)
```

Another way could be the following:

```
def display(a):
    print(*a, sep=",")

a = (10,20,30)
display(a)
```

Both ways print out: `10,20,30`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But i want a solution in which the last element should also be printed while traversing through the loop, not outside the loop

Comment: You can't use my second suggestion? Your program MUST have a loop in the function?

Comment: yes. it should have a loop

Comment: no comments on it?